# Fourier transform of a time series

Tags: physics, fourier-analysis, time-series

I have this question:

Create a time series of the function $\sin(7*\sin(140*t))$ with a sampling rate of $1000Hz$ for a time duration of $2.5s$.
Fourier transform this time series and identify the absolute value (amplitude) of the largest Fourier component in the range $0$ Hz to $450$ Hz.

My code so far is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
numpt = 2500; dt = 400; T = dt numpt;
data = Table[Sin[7*Sin[140*t]], {t, 0, T - dt, dt}];
fdata = Abs[Fourier[data]];
MaxValue[fdata]]
```

However i am struggling to find the max value in the range.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sampleRate = 1000.; duration = 2.5; dt = 1/sampleRate;
data = Table[Sin[7*Sin[140*t]], {t, 0, duration, dt}];
fdata = Abs[Fourier[data]];
todecibels[pwr_] := 10 Log10[pwr]
peaks = {#[[1]]/duration, todecibels[#[[2]]^2]} & /@ FindPeaks[fdata];
Periodogram[data, SampleRate -> sampleRate, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 600}, Full}, ScalingFunctions -> "dB", 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[peaks]}]

peaks
```

[image: hz peaks]

Your peaks are at these frequencies (in Hz), and amplitudes in dB:

```
{{0.4, -29.9564}, {22.8, -12.4852}, {67.2, 17.9721}, {112., 22.7784},
 {156.4, 21.26}, {201.2, 6.14708}, {245.6, -7.45039}, {290.4, -31.4171},
 {334.8, -43.1615}, {666.4, -43.1615}, {710.8, -31.4171}, {755.6, -7.45039}, 
 {800., 6.14708}, {844.8, 21.26}, {889.2, 22.7784}, {934., 17.9721},
 {978.4, -12.4852}, {1000.4, -29.9564}}
```

Comment: Ignore the frequencies above 500 Hz. The Fourier transform is symmetrical.

Comment: I was wondering if there a code to stop displaying the max peak after 450Hz.

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion yes, `Select[peaks, First[#]<450&]`